# I need help understanding threads utilisation

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, server, client

I'm setting up a little server with commands and other kind of stuff, but ,I don't get the thread functionement, when I connect my server it seems like everything is okay, I can connect a first client "without" problems, but when I want to connect another client it never get conected , the code runs but I can send anything I want it never shows up on the other client or the server.

I've already read the Threading documentation but even with the exemples, I don't get it, can someone give me some clues about how to proceed to handle more than just one client?

**the server code** :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3+x
import socket
import sys
from time import sleep
import threading
import random

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 33700

MSG_SIZE = 32768
serveur_on = True


CLIENT_NICK_CHAN = {} #clients" nicks dict like {nickname : channel} -> needed to easily know who is where
CLIENT_NICK_SOCKET = {} #clients" dict like {nickname : socket} -> needed to send private message to the nickname's socket easily
CLIENT_NICK_THREAD = {} #clients" dict with like {nick : thread} 


Rand_disconnection_msg = [" has drown in the abyss.", " is disconnected.", " is now in a better place.", " is now a part of our past", " passed away, in really tragic circumstances..."]
CHANNELS = ["main lobby", "test"]
CMD_LIST = [b"HELP",b"NICK",b"JOIN",b"CHANNELS",b"LEAVE"]
COMMANDS = ["/NICK <nickname>: Use only when you\'re connecting, allow you to choose a unique nickname",
            "/JOIN <channel_name>: Allow you to join or create a channel, you can\'t use this command if your are already in another channel than the" + CHANNELS[0],
            "/CHANNELS : Allow you to see every channels on the server with every connected people",
            "/LEAVE : You leave the channel your within and get bringed back to the" + CHANNELS[0],
            "/HELP : Gives you the whole command list",
            "/BYE : Disconnect ou from the server, you have to in the " + CHANNELS[0] + " to use this command"
            ]


class Colors:
    Blue, Cyan, Green, Red, Magenta, Yellow, White =b"\033[94m", b"\033[96m", b"\033[92m", b"\033[91m", b"\033[95m", b"\033[93m", b"\033[0m"
    Normal, Bold, Italics, Thin = b"\033[0m", b"\033[1m", b"\x1B[3m", b"\033[2m"


class thread_client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,conn):
        self.nom = ""
        if(self.nom == ""):
            nickname_input(connexion, self)
            print("nom : " + self.nom.decode("utf8"))
        self.channel = CHANNELS[0]
        self.admin = False
        self.adress = ""
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connexion = conn
        print("init done")


    def run(self):   
        while True:
            msgClient = self.connexion.recv(MSG_SIZE)
            if not msgClient or msgClient == b"BYE":
                break
            print(type(self.nom))
            print(type(msgClient))
            str_name = self.nom.decode("utf8")
            msg = str_name + " > " + msgClient.decode("utf8")
            print("string type name is : " + str_name + "\n")
            str_msg = msgClient.decode("utf8")
            print("{} > {}".format(str_name, str_msg))
            for clients in CLIENT_NICK_SOCKET:
                if clients != self.nom:
                    CLIENT_NICK_SOCKET[clients].send(bytes(str_msg,"utf8"))
        self.connexion.send(b"You are now disconnected.\n")
        self.connexion.close()
        del CLIENT_NICK_SOCKET[self.nom.decode("utf8")]
        del CLIENT_NICK_CHAN[self.nom.decode("utf8")]
        rand_leave = random.randint(0, len(Rand_disconnection_msg)-1)
        leaving_msg = Rand_disconnection_msg[rand_leave]
        print(str_name + leaving_msg + "\n")


def nickname_input(client_socket, thread):
    print("now in input nickname")
    msg_nom = client_socket.recv(MSG_SIZE)
    print("msg_nom = " + msg_nom.decode("utf8"))
    msg_nom_arr = msg_nom.split()
    if not msg_nom_arr[0]:
        client_socket.send(b"Please send a non void message")
        nickname_input(client_socket, thread)
    print("msg_nom_arr[0] = " + str(msg_nom_arr[0]))
    if(msg_nom_arr[0] == b"NICK"):
        if(len(msg_nom_arr)== 1):
            client_socket.send(b"Please do not just enter '/NICK' -> you have to type '/NICK <your_nickname>', please proceed again :\n")
            nickname_input(client_socket, thread)
        else:
            thread.nom = msg_nom_arr[1]
    else:
        client_socket.send(b"It seems like you forgot to use '/NICK' before entering your nickname, please proceed again:\n")
        nickname_input(client_socket, thread)
    return   


def print_channels(client_socket, thread):
    client_socket.send(b"Here\'s the current channel list :\n\n")
    for chan in CHANNELS:
        sleep(0.70)
        client_socket.send( bytes(chan,"utf8") + b":\n    current members :\n")
        for chan_user in CLIENT_NICK_CHAN:
            if(CLIENT_NICK_CHAN[chan_user] == chan):
               sleep(0.35)
               if(chan_user == thread.nom):
                    if(thread.admin):
                       client_socket.send(b"          " +Colors.Bold + Colors.Yellow + b"@"+ thread.nom + b"@" + Colors.Normal + b"\n")
                    else:
                        client_socket.send(b"          " +Colors.Bold + Colors.Yellow + thread.nom + Colors.Normal + b"\n")
               else:
                    client_socket.send(b"       " +bytes(chan_user,"utf8") +  b"@\n")
        client_socket.send(b"\n")
    client_socket.send(b"\n")
    return


def join_channel(client_socket, thread, data, data_array):
    if(not data_arr[1]):
        connexion.send(b"Please select a channel you want to join using '/JOIN <channel_name>'\nNote that if the channel you asked for doesn\'t exists a new channel <channel_name> will be created and you will be the administrator of this channel")
        return
    else:
        asked_channel = data_arr[1]
        if( not (asked_channel in CHANNELS)):
            thread.channel = asked_channel
            thread.admin = True
            connexion.send(b"Welcome in " + asked_channel + b" channel, since you\'re the on who created this channel you are granted as administrator for this channel")
            connexion.send(b"Note that being administrator allow you tu use some new commands as '/GRANT', '/REVOKE' or  '/REN', for more information please use '/HELP'")
        else:
            thread.channel = asked_channel
            connexion.send(b"Welcome in " + asked_channel + b" channel !")
    return


SERVER = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
SERVER.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
try:
    SERVER.bind((HOST,PORT))
except socket.error:
    print("Server connexion failed")
    sys.exit()
print("Server is now connected\nWaiting for connexions...\n")


SERVER.listen(5)


connexion, adresse = SERVER.accept()
thread = thread_client(connexion)
thread.start()

print("thread type = " +str(type(thread)) +"\n")
print("thread = ")
print(thread)
connexion.send(bytes("Welcome ","utf8") + Colors.Yellow + Colors.Bold + thread.nom + Colors.Normal)
nick = thread.nom #type -> bytes
str_nick = nick.decode("utf8")
CLIENT_NICK_CHAN[str_nick] = thread.channel
CLIENT_NICK_SOCKET[str_nick] = connexion
CLIENT_NICK_THREAD[str_nick] = thread
print("client list : ")
print(CLIENT_NICK_CHAN)
print("\n")
print("CLIENT_NICK_SOCKET = ")
print(CLIENT_NICK_SOCKET)
print("\n")
while serveur_on:
    conn_msg = str_nick + " joined the chat\n"
    print(conn_msg)
    connexion.send(b"hello world 3\n\n")
    connexion.send(b"*" * 80 + b"\n")
    connexion.send(Colors.Red + Colors.Bold + b"\nWELCOME IN THE MAIN LOBBY \n" + Colors.Normal+b"\nTo enter a channel use '/JOIN <channel_name>'\nthe <channel_name> have to be composed by one world or use underscores to join words\nIf the channel does not exists a new one will be created\n\nNote that you have to be in another channel than the main lobby to chat\n")
    print_channels(connexion, thread)
    connexion.send(b"*" * 80 + b"\n\n")
    while True:
        print("thread list = ")
        print(CLIENT_NICK_THREAD)
        data = connexion.recv(MSG_SIZE) #receiving data from client
        data_arr= data.split() #convert data into an array to check if the first word in the message is "MSG" or not
        print(str_nick +" is now in -> " + thread.channel + "\n") 
        if(data_arr[0] in CMD_LIST):
            if(data.startswith(b"HELP")): #HELP CMD
                for command in COMMANDS:
                    connexion.send(bytes(command,"utf") + b"\n")
            if(data.startswith(b"CHANNELS")): #Channels + current members CMD
               connexion.send(b"\n")
               print_channel(connexion, thread)
               connexion.send(b"\n")
            if(data.startswith(b"JOIN")):
                join_channel(connexion, thread, data, data_arr)
                connexion.send(b"\n")



        else:
            if ((thread.channel != CHANNELS[0]) and (data.startswith("MSG"))):
                for chan_user in thread.channel:
                    chan_user.send(nick + b" > " + bytes(data,"utf8"))
                    print("data = " + data)
            elif (thread.channel == CHANNELS[0]):
                connexion.send(b"You have to be in another channel than the " + bytes(CHANNELS[0], "utf8") + b" to start chating !\nPlease use '/JOIN <channel_name>' or '/HELP' to learn how to join another channel.\n\n")
```

**and the client code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3+x
host = ''
port = 33700
MSG_SIZE = 32768
emission_stop = False

import socket
import sys
import threading
import time


def Tsend():
    while True:
        msg_envoi = input("> ")
        if msg_envoi.startswith("/"):
            msg_envoi = msg_envoi.replace("/","",1)
        else:
            msg_envoi = msg_envoi
        CLIENT.send(bytes(msg_envoi,"utf8"))
        if emission_stop:
            CLIENT.close()

def Trecv():
    while True:
        msg_recu = CLIENT.recv(MSG_SIZE).decode("utf8")
        print("\n" + msg_recu)
        if not msg_recu:
            break
    emission_stop = True
    print("connexion lost\n")
    CLIENT.close()

CLIENT = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
try:
    CLIENT.connect((host,port))
except socket.error:
    print("connexion failed\n")
    sys.exit()
print("Now connected to the server on port: {}\n".format(port))
print("Please now enter your nickname using '/NICK'\n")
thread_emission = threading.Thread(target = Tsend)
thread_reception = threading.Thread(target = Trecv)
thread_emission.start()
thread_reception.start()
```

What I want is just to have multiple clients that are allowed to talk to each other but I can't even get two clients.

Comment: this is entirely too much code, you need to provide a Minimum Viable Complete Example for people to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem I can see is that you are only calling `SERVER.accept()` once. This means you will only ever accept 1 client connection. When using blocking sockets as you are, a typical approach is to keep doing `SERVER.accept()` inside a loop so that you can keep accepting all client sockets. After you `accept()` a new socket, you create new thread(s) dedicated to sending/receiving for that socket, so that you don't block the accepting thread. And then you continue accepting more connections. Something like this:

```
#SERVER:
while serveur_on:
    connexion, adresse = SERVER.accept()

    # Possibly do some limited IO with client socket here, but be careful not
    # to block this thread too long because that will prevent more clients from
    # connecting.

    thread = thread_client(connexion)
    thread.start()

    # No more client IO on this thread, it's the client thread's job now.
```

You seem to have code that communicates with the client (receiving messages and sending responses) in 2 different places: on the main thread after you `SERVER.accept()`, and up in `thread_client.run()`. It doesn't make sense that way, it should all be in `thread_client.run()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @almiki i'm going to try what you said with the accept method within a loop and review again my code.

Comment: It works fine now, the problem was exactly what you said, I just tried with 3 clients and they could connect proprely, thanks again.